# Search directories in Emacs

Tags: eclipse, search, emacs, grep

I recently switched from Eclipse to Emacs and one feature that I really miss is Eclipse file search. It allows you to search a whole project very accurately (albeit very slowly) for a particular search term. In Emacs I have been using `M-x rgrep` but it doesn't seem to give reliable results. For example, If I search for 0.1 it will not return results for lines of code containing '0.1' (a match surrounded by quotation marks).

Can anyone suggest a more accurate alternative to `rgrep`?

Comment: Assuming that one of `0.1` and `1.0` is a typo (and noting that as rgrep takes a regexp, you probably meant to use `\.` in that pattern), it should be matching that just fine.

Comment: @phils thanks, I have retested and you are right 0.1 does show up in the results. Can you expand on your point about 'rgrep takes a regexp'? so should I be using regex in my search terms or just using the search term string?

Comment: Emacs' `rgrep` function calls the `grep` program, so the pattern you pass it needs to be a valid patten for grep. In general grep regexp syntax is extremely similar to Emacs regexp syntax, but you shouldn't forget that it's a different program. The rgrep output shows you the exact command being executed; the call to grep will be at (or near) the end, if you want to check the exact arguments used on your system. `man grep` will of course detail the syntax for your system, and the following URL may also help: http://www.regular-expressions.info/grep.html

Comment: @phils thanks for the info, I will definitely read that. I have since realized that I was doing something silly. If I call the grep command when looking at a PHP file, for example, it will then default to searching *.php, unless I specify *. I am now getting more accurate results.

Comment: rgrep keeps a history of filename patterns, so if you want to re-use a previous pattern but it isn't offered by default, you can easily retrieve it from the history in the minibuffer. For this reason, unless you have very few non-code files in the tree (or few files in total), you may find it better to supply a space-separated list of filename patterns (e.g. `*.php *.inc`; note that `C-q SPC` will enter a space if plain `SPC` doesn't work) rather than a single `*`, as that will result in a more efficient find/grep.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend use "igrep" lib for searhing in files,  you can find it [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/igrep.el).
To start using add this rows to your .emacs file (don't forget to igrep.el to emacs-path, it can be ~/.emacs.d/ for example):

```
(require 'igrep)
(global-set-key "\C-cf" 'igrep-find)
```

So you can start search by using [C-cf], it ask pattern for file names in search, and query to search. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [ack](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Ack). It can intelligently ignore files you don't want to search (e.g. version control directories).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend beagrep if you are working on large projects such as linux kernel or android.

It takes a desktop search engine beagle and grep together, so common programming grep tasks can be done very quickly. For e.g., grepping for readlink in android source code can take me more than half an hour, with beagrep, it only takes half a second.

Check out my [github page](http://baohaojun.github.com/beagrep.html).

Answer (score 0):

`M-x multi-occur-in-matching-buffers` takes a regex to select the buffers you wish to search in, and a second regex to search for the item you're looking for.

A common workflow with emacs is to never (or only rarely) close a buffer in a project when working on that project, and so after you've been hacking around for a while, you'll likely have most files open anyway. Of course, if you don't work like this, then using `multi-occur...` is of less use.